# Barra de progreso en div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, progressbar

estoy intentando hacer que un div, según el valor de una variable(0-100), tenga una barra de progreso más o menos grande. Lo he intentando con el objeto "progressbar" de html, pero no funciona, también he intentado colocar otro div encima y que vaya cambiando el height, pero tampoco me ha dado resultados. ¿Alguien sabe como lo puedo hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques el código que has intentado a ver cual es el error que tenés.

Comment: Hola, puede optar por usar una libreria de diseño las cuales ya vienen con estas soluciones como boostrap

Comment: O puedes revisar como lo hacen y los estilos que usan y los copias y modificas de acuerdo con tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la misma idea de Agustin Silva en su respuesta, puedes poner un div encima de otro, pero en lugar de cambiar la clase yo diría que cambies el width de la barra directamente, y te ahorras las clases CSS.

```js
const barraProgreso = document.getElementById('barra-progreso');
const cantidadProgreso = document.getElementById('cantidad-progreso');
let progreso = 0;

const intervalo = setInterval(() => {
  progreso++;
  const porcentaje = `${progreso}%`;
  barraProgreso.style.width = porcentaje;
  cantidadProgreso.innerHTML = porcentaje;
  progreso = progreso % 100;
}, 20);
```

```css
#contenedor-barra-progreso {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

#barra-progreso {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#cantidad-progreso {
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor-barra-progreso">
  <div id="barra-progreso"></div>
  <span id="cantidad-progreso">0%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sii tambien pense en eso. Pero no estaba seguro de si se iba a renderizar en el DOM, Esta manera si funciona es mas efectiva :D

Answer (score 1):

Si no estas trabajando con ningun *framework* de *FrontEnd* lo unico que se me ocurre (y es bastante rústico) es que crees un `div` con un `width` y `heigth` prestablecidos (ejemplo: **500px** y **100px**).

Luego que dentro crees otro `div` dentro de ese con `background-color:green` y `height:100%;`.

Y agrégale una `class` **0porciento**

Y en el *css* creas clases **0porciento**, **5porciento**, **10porciento**, ..., etc, las cuales tengan distinto `width`. Ejemplo: `width:0%`, `width:5%`, `width:10%`.

Y luego con *Javascript* a medida que va subiendo el **contador**, tienes que ir cambiando la clase **0porciento** por la clase **5porciento**.

```
<div class="barra-completa"><div id="barra-carga" class="0porciento"></div></div>
```

Y en el *css*

```
.barra-completa{width:500px;height:300px} #barra-carga{height:100%,background-color:green;}.0porciento{width:0%} .5porciento{width:5%} .10porciento{width:10%}
```

Luego en el *Javascript*

```
const barra= Document.getElementById("#barra-carga");
let contador=0;
    contador=5;
    if contador>=5:
      barra.classList.remove("0porciento");
      barra.classList.add("5porciento");
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, aunque el código parece más Python que Javascript.

Comment: Si puede ser, hace rato no trabajo con Javascript. Pero la logica es la misma